# R, selectively removing parts of a string

Tags: r, string

I'm having trouble thinking of an efficient way to remove parts from a string using R.
I have text data that I'm reading into R.  The data is in HTML, which kind of looks like this:

```
dummy <- c("Blah Blah 10pt margins blah blah 11pt blah format 23pt real answer34")
```

I'm trying to isolate only that "34", but, I can't simply pull out numbers because of all the "10pt" and "11pt" and "23pt" html formatting.

What I would like to do is, for every instance where I find the text "pt," remove the two characters in front of "pt".  If I do that, I can get:

```
newDummy <- c("Blah Blah pt margins blah blah pt blah format pt real answer34")
```

Then I can get my answer of 34 via `str_extract_all(newDummy,"\\(?[0-9,.]+\\)?")` from the stringr library.

The problem is that I can't seem to efficiently turn "dummy" into "newDummy" -- does anyone have a neat solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use:

```
dummy <- c("Blah Blah 10pt margins blah blah 11pt blah format 23pt real answer34")
library(stringi)
stri_extract_all_regex(dummy,'\\d+?\\d(?!pt)')[[1]]
#[1] "34"
```

or

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(dummy, "\\b\\d+\\b")[[1]]
#[1] "34"
```

#### Update

```
dummy <- "10pt 11pt realanswer34"
stri_extract_all_regex(dummy,'\\d+?\\d(?!pt)')[[1]]
#[1] "34"
```

or using `str_extract_all`

```
str_extract_all(dummy,perl('\\d+?\\d(?!pt)'))[[1]]
#[1] "34"
```

Comment: Thanks akrun, but there's another little wrinkle to my question that I didn't think about (will edit original question).  What if my "real answer" is not formatted so that the number stands alone?  For example, dummy <- c("10pt 11pt realanswer34").  In that case, how would I get the 34?

Comment: @ZZ123 My first option still gets you `34`